# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am transferring file from one s3 bucket to another bucket. File size is more than 8GB.
Please find the code snippet below:-

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3_client = boto3.client("s3",
    aws_access_key_id="myaccesskey",
    aws_secret_access_key="mysecretaccesskey" , config=Config(signature_version='s3v4',read_timeout=65)                     
    )
    
copy_source_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_key_name}
tgt_bucket = s3.Bucket(trgt_bckt)
s3_client.copy(copy_source_object,trgt_bckt,trgt_key)
```

but i am getting issue i.e. **botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema in < script >**

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: you can use `copy_from` and check if its working for you. `S3.Object(dest_bucket, new_key).copy_from(CopySource=copy_source_object)`.

Comment: @Abhishek source and target bucket both are different and file size is more than 5GB. we need multipart transfer for this. and client.copy supports multipart transfer. but not sure how to fix the given issue.

Comment: this might help https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object